# Why in Windows might attempting to delete a file twice work?

Tags: php, windows, git, permission-denied, phing

I've been pulling my hair out trying to write a continuous integration script with PHP for the Windows machine I develop on.

Having cloned a Git repository, I was unable to make a script that deleted it all. (The .git folder and everything in them). I was getting "Permission denied" errors.

It seemed intermittent. I tried Phing, but that failed but lead me to [this Phing ticket](https://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/956), so I'm not alone - but that solution using `attrib` didn't work for me.

I finally realised that it was just taking two attempts to delete some folders and/or files within it. So my PHP code that finally worked, was this:

```
<?php
function delTree($dir, $ignore = array()) {

    // no need to continue if $dir doesn't exist
    if (!file_exists($dir))
        return true;

    // must not continue if it's a link. trigger an error.
    if (is_link($dir)) {
        trigger_error("Cannot delete $dir: it's a link.", E_ERROR);
        return false;
    }

    // if it's a file, delete it and return.
    if (is_file($dir)) {
        return tryUnlink($dir, 2);
    }

    // it's a directory. so...
    // build an array of files/directories within it to delete
    $files = array_diff(
            scandir($dir), array('.', '..'), $ignore
    );

    // delete each directory within $dir
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        delTree("$dir/$file", $ignore);
    }

    // delete $dir itself
    return tryRmdir($dir, 2);
}
function tryUnlink($file, $attempts = 2){
    $result = unlink($file);
    if (!$result) {
        if ($attempts > 1){
            return tryUnlink($file, $attempts--);
        } else {
            trigger_error("Cannot delete file $file", E_ERROR);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function tryRmdir($dir, $attempts = 2){
    $result = rmdir($dir);
    if (!$result) {
        if ($attempts > 1){
            return tryRmdir($dir, $attempts--);
        } else {
            trigger_error("Cannot delete directory $dir", E_ERROR);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And calling them with the `$attempts` argument set to 2 solved everything (12 hours later).

I'd tried things like `chmod`ing the file to `0666`, closing the IDE, closing SourceTree, any open explorer windows, wearing a tin foil hat, and even calling `exec()` with commands like:

```
rm -r .git -Force
rmdir .git /s /q
```

and probably 10 others that are buried somewhere in my repo now.

What might the cause have been?

Comment: Can you even `unlink()` a directory? Thought it was for files only.

Comment: don't forget you can't remove a directory if ANY process is using anything in/below that directory.

Comment: @MarcB, but then why would attempting to delete an empty dir or a file twice in a row work every time without fail? Whereas just the once, would fail?

Comment: you return from delTree if given path is a file ...

Comment: @Jodes: because you're NOT trying just twice. you're doing `$attempts--`, which means the ORIGINAL value of $attempts (`2`) get passed into tryUnlink() and tryRmdir() each time. that means it's an infinite recursive loop, and you just keep trying until it finally does delete.

Comment: @m02ph3u5: `function foo($x) { echo $x; } $a = 2; foo($x--)` will print out `2`. in OP's case, since 2>1 is true, it'll just call tryUnlink AGAIN with the same `2` value, over and over. each level of recursion will only execute twice, but since it recurses infinitely...

Comment: so I made a typo in the comment, and $a = 2 should've been $x = 2;. still applies: it's an infniite loop, see the wiki answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Both you functions `tryUnlink()` and `tryRmdir()` will cause an infinite loop (unless it's actually deleted). Look at the following snippet + output.

code:

```
<?php

function foo ($attempts = 2) {
   echo "attempts = $attempts\n";
   if ($attempts > 1) {
      foo ($attempts--);
   } else {
      echo "returning with \$attempts <= 1\n";
  }
}
foo(2);
```

output:

```
attempts = 2
attempts = 2
attempts = 2
[...many many many dupes...]
attempts = 2
attempts = 2
attempts = 2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Given that it's not said that deletion kicks in on the second run.

Comment: ah, I get it, you're right, prefix/postfix makes the difference - better make this a good answer to the original question, I'll delete my part of the above discussion

Comment: exactly `--$x` does the subtraction FIRST, then passes the result down as the argument. `$x--` passes the original value, THEN subtracts, leaving the subtracted value at the top of the infinite recursive call stack. if the recursive call woudl ever have returned, then at some point you'd have gotten `attempts = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

As of Windows 7 (or perhaps Vista?) it is rare, but not abnormal, for the first attempt to remove a directory tree to fail.  I think this due to a race condition due to the deletions being processed asynchronously by the file system.

As you've already discovered, you can work around this by retrying the operation; personally, I've never seen it fail twice in a row, though I usually allow it to retry three or four times to be on the safe side.

Comment: Interesting, thanks - do you have any more information on that?

Comment: No, just my own experience.  Didn't happen in XP as far as I can remember.  Note that if you're seeing this consistently (more often than say, one time in ten) there's probably a specific reason, e.g., anti-virus software.